# Validate select with rule (JQuery Validate)

Tags: jquery, select, validation

For a select input like this:

```
<select id="sn" name="sn_arvo">
    <option value="">Valitse nopeus</option>
    <option value="0">10</option>
    <option value="1">20</option>
    <option value="2">30</option>
</select>
```

if I add `class="required"` in the select node, validation works fine. But if I add it to rules:

```
$("#vikaformi").validate({
    debug: true,
rules: {
        sn: {
            required: true
        }
```

the select is not validated. Rules for text inputs for example are working. I'm using validate 1.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldnt you use `sn_arvo` instead?

> Key/value pairs defining custom rules. Key is the name of an element

```
sn_arvo: {
            required: true
        }
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions